# Django: how to change manytomany inline text with no intermediate table?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When you have what I call "intermediate" ManyToMany tables, it's easy, like that:

```
class Interrogation(models.Model):
    phrases = models.ManyToManyField(Phrase, blank=True,
                                     through='InterrogationPhrase',
                                     symmetrical=False,
                                     related_name='phrase')

class InterrogationPhrase(models.Model):
    interrogation = models.ForeignKey(Interrogation, blank=False)
    phrase = models.ForeignKey(Phrase, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'({0}) - {1} - {2}'.format(
            self.importance, self.interrogation, self.phrase
        )
```

With the code above, in the "`Inline`" admin, it shows the `__str__` of `InterrogationPhrase` if I just declare like that:

```
class InterrogationPhrasesInline(CollapsedStackedInline):
    model = InterrogationPhrase
    fk_name = 'interrogation'
    fields = ('phrase')
    extra = 0
    verbose_name = _(u"Phrase")
    verbose_name_plural = _(u"Phrases")
```

But how to deal when I dont want intermediate declaration and I just want to write:

```
class Mot(models.Model):
    groupes = models.ManyToManyField(Groupe)
```

without declaring a `MotGroupe` table (which is allowed in Django)? My admin looks like that:

```
class MotGroupesInline(CollapsedStackedInline):
    model = Mot.groupes.through
    extra = 0
    verbose_name = _(u"Groupe")
    verbose_name_plural = _(u"Groupes")

class MotAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MotGroupesInline,)
```

But the problem is that the inline is shown with, for each row of `Groupe`, this text: `Groupe: Mot_groupes object`. This is both ugly and useless. How to change that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).

My `models.py`:

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class Groupe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Mot(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    groupes = models.ManyToManyField(Groupe)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class MotGroupeProxy(Mot.groupes.through):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.groupe)
```

My `admin.py`:

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from so_34111398_manytomany_inline.models import Mot, Groupe, MotGroupeProxy


class MotGroupesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MotGroupeProxy
    extra = 0 
    verbose_name = _(u"Groupe")
    verbose_name_plural = _(u"Groupes")


@admin.register(Mot)
class MotAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MotGroupesInline,)


@admin.register(Groupe)
class GroupeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

And the result is http://screencloud.net/v/eN4K

Comment: I check your solution as valid because that's what I've done but I wanted something more simple. I thought there was a way to avoid `MotGroupeProxy`... Django is so powerful there are usually tons of shortcuts.

Comment: What is your Django plugin for changing the admin interface?

Comment: I've spent a good amount of time digging Django internals to see other options. For me proxy is the best but you can create a special admin template for sure https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/stacked.html. That is the new Admin UI in Django 1.9